# SQL Server strange distinct query

Tags: sql-server

I use SQL Server 2008, C#, I have a table which contains about 20000 rows, I have several similar rows in this table, there are about 900 distinct rows, it is my table structure:

**tblCourse**

```
courselevel, coursecode, coursename, branchcode...
```

For example I have 20 rows with the same `coursecode/coursename` but with different `branchcode` or `courselevel`, I'm going to have a table which contains item with only unique `coursecode`.

here is a little sample of my table:

```
... courselevel=1,coursecode=1200,coursename=A,branchcode=200...
... courselevel=2,coursecode=1200,coursename=A,branchcode=200...
... courselevel=1,coursecode=1200,coursename=A,branchcode=220...
... courselevel=1,coursecode=1200,coursename=A,branchcode=230...
... courselevel=1,coursecode=1200,coursename=A,branchcode=240...
... courselevel=1,coursecode=1200,coursename=A,branchcode=250...
... courselevel=2,coursecode=1200,coursename=A,branchcode=251...
... courselevel=1,coursecode=1200,coursename=A,branchcode=225...
```

I want to have only the first row:

```
... courselevel=1,coursecode=1200,coursename=A,branchcode=200...
```

because all rows have similar coursecode,

What should I do?

How should I write my select query string?

I have tested different methods (group by, distinct, max(ID)...) with no luck, please help me!

thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: OK so you have that table with 20'000 rows - and **what** do you want to extract from it?? You're not being very clear on what your goal is, what kind of data you want to get out of your table ... please rephrase and show samples

Comment: oh yes I've updated my question, I hope it can help, I want to have only records that have unique coursecode

Comment: And what values for the other columns would you like to show? Why branchcode 200 io 225 for example.

Comment: You need to define how to pick the "best" version of each field, or the "best" row per courselevel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY` the similar columns and use any [Aggregate Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) on the other columns to have them just return one record. *What* that one value would be entirely depends on the aggregate function you use.

[Aggregate Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

> Aggregate functions perform a calculation on a set of values and
>   return a single value. Except for COUNT, aggregate functions ignore
>   null values. Aggregate functions are frequently used with the GROUP BY
>   clause of the SELECT statement

In this example, I have used the min/max and avg aggregate functions.

```
SELECT  courselevel
        , coursecode
        , coursename
        , MIN(branchcode)
        , MAX(othercolumn)
        , AVG(numberColumn)
        , ...
FROM    yourTable
GROUP BY
        courselevel
        , coursecode
        , coursename
```

Comment: I use this query:select coursename,coursecode, MIN(branchcode),MIN(levelcode) from tblCourse group by levelcode, coursecode, coursename, and it is again giving me too many results, it seems rows with similar branchcode or levelcode are being retured, but I do not want to have items with similiar branchcode or levelcode, what should I do now? thanks

Comment: You can't be grouping by levelcode and applying an aggregate function over it?! Please post your actual query and it's not clear to me what you really need. If you are grouping on levelcode, coursecode and coursename, it is quit possible for distinct groups to have the same branchcode.

Comment: oh, thanks, it is my query: course_query = "select coursename,coursecode, MIN(branchcode),MIN(levelcode) from tblCourse group by levelcode, coursecode, coursename";, what is going wrong here? it should return about 900 records while it gave more than 4000!